Find a json value in a jsonb array
I have a jsonb[] column in my table named jsonb_column, which contains an array of JSONB objects. For example:
jsonb_column = '{"{\"title\":\"title1\"}"
                ,"{\"title\":\"title2\"}"}'

I'm attempting to extract the JSONB object where the title field is equal to 'title2'.
SELECT *
FROM tablename,
jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_column) AS job
WHERE job->>'title' = 'title2';

It doesn't return anything. How to do it properly?

A mix-up of jsonb[] (containing jsonb values that, in turn, contain a plain JSON object) with a JSON array stored as jsonb.
Type jsonb[]
jsonb[] is a Postgres array. To unnest, use unnest():
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, js jsonb[]);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, '{"{\"title\":\"title1\"}","{\"title\":\"title2\"}"}')
;

SELECT *
FROM   tbl, unnest(js) AS job
WHERE  job->>'title' = 'title2';

fiddle - dbfiddle currently swallows necessary backslashes in the display. I reported a bug.
Related:

How to use LIKE on elements of a JSONB array?

JSON array in type jsonb
This is where you could use jsonb_array_elements() like you tried:
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, js jsonb);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (1, '[{"title":"title1"},{"title":"title2"}]')
;

SELECT *
FROM   tbl, jsonb_array_elements(js) AS job
WHERE  job->>'title' = 'title2';

fiddle
See:

Query for array elements inside JSON type

But for big tables it's a lot more efficient to filter with the jsonb contains operator @>:
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  js @> '[{"title":"title2"}]';

Or with a SQL/JSON path expression:
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  js @? '$[*] ? (@.title == "title2")';

fiddle
The last two can use a GIN index like:
CREATE INDEX tbl_js_gin_idx ON tbl USING gin (js jsonb_path_ops);

See:

Find rows containing a key in a JSONB array of records
Index for finding an element in a JSON array
Query JSON array of objects against multiple values

